# Looping over a dataset asynchronously

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm having Rust/tokio in mind while asking this question, but I think it's generic enough to apply to any mode of cooperative multitasking.

One of the tasks my system needs to perform every second is to iterate over a dataset of 100,000 elements and do some very **inexpensive** operation with each of them (for example, filtering). The result will be posted to a channel that has a small buffer - so there will be a few elements ready-for-consumption while new ones are generated.

The only way I can think of making this code cooperative is to break the loop down into chunks and creating one task per chunk. But this is a burden on the developer as figuring out the ideal "chunk size" can be challenging.

That makes me think OS threads (e.g. preemption) are a better approach for this kind of , accepting the cost of context switching and leaving the optimization to the OS.

Am I correct in thinking like this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand: are you just trying to parallelize the work? That is, will a library like [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon) but for async tasks be good for you?